# Accents problems when using lstdefinestyle

Tags: pdftex, accents

i'm a new user of Latex, and I've got an issue, here is the style I'm using :
[image]

but when i use some accents like "é" or "à", I've got that error :

! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.

Can someone help me to understand why, and fix it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please don't add your code as an image, we can't cut and paste it.

Comment: Could you please make a short example document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that reproduces your problem? Make it as short as possible while it is still complete, i.e., it still compiles and produces the error you describe.

Comment: Are you saving your file in UTF-8 encoding? That could happen if you saved in an 8-bit character set.